# how to move and format element values to its subelement using XSLT/XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

My Application receives a file which contains several values in the lowest element named "si" and I need to break some of them in subelement named "ssi" because the Other Application will accept only this way. No all "si" will be broken in "ssi", only some of them according to internall rules. Additionally, all elements that came as "ssi" in the input file must be grouped under "si 999".

In the xml below, "si" stands for subitem and "ssi" for sub-subitem and "sf" for subfield. "sf" appears only in output and it is the lowest element possible. It happens here because certain codes are acctually a group of sub-codes and the input file doesn't separate them in the lowest as possible but the Another Application will expect this way.

For instance:

```
<c:si name="001" value="1234"/>
```

needs to be transformed in

```
<c:si name="001">
 <c:ssi name="sf1" value="12"/>
 <c:ssi name="sf2" value="34"/>
<\c:si>
```

while

```
<c:si name="002" value="abcd"/>
```

will suffer no change, so the output will be exact the same. In other words, there is certain internal business rule that says that si 001 is in fact a join of two sub-codes while si 002 is just a single code. The internal input doesn't show it and the output must make it clear according to the example below.

And all input ssi must be moved under si name="999"

For instance:

```
<c:ssi name="0001" value="123456"/>
<c:ssi name="0002" value="abcdef"/>
```

become in the xml output:

```
<c:si name="999">
 <c:ssi name="0001" value="123456"/>
 <c:ssi name="0002" value="abcdef"/>
</c:si>
```

Here the entire example:

input xml

```
<c:product xmlns:c="myapp">
       <c:item>
              <c:si name="001" value="1234"/>
              <c:ssi name="0001" value="123456"/>
              <c:si name="002" value="abcd"/>
              <c:ssi name="0002" value="abcdef"/>
       </c:item>
       <c:item>
              <c:si name="001" value="9876"/>
              <c:ssi name="0001" value="987654"/>
              <c:si name="002" value="ghij"/>
              <c:ssi name="0002" value="lmnopq"/>
       </c:item>
</c:product>
```

Desired output file:

```
<c:product xmlns:c="myapp">
       <c:item>
              <c:si name="001">
                 <c:ssi name="sf1" value="12"/>
                 <c:ssi name="sf2" value="34"/>
              <\c:si>

              <c:si name="002" value="abcd"/>

              <c:si name="999">
                 <c:ssi name="0001" value="123456"/>
                 <c:ssi name="0002" value="abcdef"/>
              <\c:si>
       </c:item>
       <c:item>
              <c:si name="001">
                 <c:ssi name="sf1" value="98"/>
                 <c:ssi name="sf2" value="76"/>
              <\c:si>

              <c:si name="002" value="ghij"/>

              <c:si name="999">
                 <c:ssi name="0001" value="987654"/>
                 <c:ssi name="0002" value="lmnopq"/>
              <\c:si>
       </c:item>
</c:product>
```

Today, I am adjusting the output by parsing the input file and using few temporary variables. Recently, I learned about XSLT/XSL and found amazing how usefull it can be in my scenario. If it was just few elements XSL would already be very usefull but since it is a really a good amount, it becomes even more suitable for my case. You can imagine how big it is the effort when you think I can have untill 100 si and untill 1000 ssi.

So, how can I move all incoming ssi to si 999 and how can I apply a XSL that transform element value in "sf"? It will make much easier to mantain the application if I can have a XSL file/block for each transformation.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:c="myapp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <c:si name="001">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="c:si[@name='001']"/>
        </c:si>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="c:si[not(@name='001')]"/>
        <c:si name="999">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="c:ssi"/>
        </c:si>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:si[@name='001']">
    <c:ssi name="sf1" value="{substring(@value, 1, 2)}"/>
    <c:ssi name="sf2" value="{substring(@value, 3, 2)}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this creates the 001 and 999 subitems regardless of whether they have content or not.